# Return image using API - Pure NodeJS (no Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to return an image when a user connects to the server ip address, in short, create an API that returns an image.

I had found this solution that worked however now I don't know why it doesn't work.

I don't want to use Express or similar.

UPDATE

Without `res.end()` it works, but I don't understand why.

```
import http from 'http';
import mime from 'mime';
import fs from 'fs';

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 8000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': mime.getType('./tmp/screenshot.png') });
    fs.createReadStream('./tmp/screenshot.png').pipe(res);
    res.end();
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: What's your question? Why you can't close the stream before you've send the data?

Comment: Please read the description of the tags you use. The API tag starts with: _**DO NOT USE.**_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in:

```js
 fs.createReadStream('./tmp/screenshot.png').pipe(res);
```

you already add a `pipe` to send data between the server and the client and after finishing sending data, it automatically triggers the `end()` event.
if you don't want this behavior. just do this

```js
 fs.createReadStream('./tmp/screenshot.png').pipe(res, {end:false});
```

I hope it's help you :)